# spark-jobserver and mllib issue running jobs

Tags: scala, rest, apache-spark, spark-jobserver

I'm experimenting with the `JobServer` and would like to use it in our production environment.

I want to use `mllib` and `spark-jobserver` together, but i got a error (at the spark-jobserver, when a job is sended).

```
job-server[ERROR] Uncaught error from thread [JobServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[JobServer]
job-server[ERROR] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/mllib/stat/Statistics$
job-server[ERROR]   at SparkCorrelation$.getCorrelation(SparkCorrelation.scala:50)
job-server[ERROR]   at SparkCorrelation$.runJob(SparkCorrelation.scala:28)
job-server[ERROR]   at SparkCorrelation$.runJob(SparkCorrelation.scala:11)
job-server[ERROR]   at spark.jobserver.JobManagerActor$$anonfun$spark$jobserver$JobManagerActor$$getJobFuture$4.apply(JobManagerActor.scala:234)
```

I am using `spark-jobserver 0.5.0` and `spark 1.2`.

any idea about it?

Code:

```
def getCorrelation(sc: SparkContext):Double={
        val pathFile = "hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hduser/correlacion.csv"
        val fileData = getFileData(sc,pathFile)
        val colX = getDoubleColumn(fileData,1)
        val colY = getDoubleColumn(fileData,2)
        Statistics.corr(colX,colY,"pearson")
    }

override def runJob(sc: SparkContext, config: Config): Any = {/*
    val dd = sc.parallelize(config.getString("input.string").split(" ").toSeq)
    dd.map((_, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _).collect().toMap*/
    getCorrelation(sc)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you still want to know.
Just use `SPARK-CLASSPATH` to link to MLlib in local mode.

Alternatively, just modify Dependencies.scala to access Mllib. Just add it to the sequence in the `lazy val SparkDeps`.

Both solutions found here:

https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/issues/341

https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/issues/138